# Integrating LinkedIn API in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linkedin-api

I am trying to create a portal where users after login can search other members, update their own profiles etc. I want to integrate every users LinkedIn profile to the website so that when anyone is searching for a member, the results should be the as per the LinkedIn profile of that person being searched for.

Moreover I'm using PHP and MySQL database in the back end.

How to enable this feature in my website using the LinkedIn API ?

Answer (score 1):

You would download a wrapper for php to interact with the LinkedIn API first....

[LINKED IN PHP WRAPPER](https://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/)

Then from there you would create a database to store new users names, and ids' along with their l=LinkedIn email.  Which will be the reference to their linked in profile.

Which you would give them the option to login via LinkedIn, with oAuth.

Some helpful links to get you started...
But if you don't know much about PHP or programming in general.  This might all seem very confusing at first

[TUTORIAL 1](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-login-with-linkedin-oauth-in-php_185.html)

[Simple LinkedIn PHP library](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2355)

[Getting OAuth token](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token-php)

Comment: Why the downvote.  The question is quite ambiguous and I answered it with valid starting point links.  Whats the problem??